# git operations throwing 'broken pipe' error

Tags: linux, git

I am using git 2.10 on SLES11 OS.

When I issue 'git diff' or 'git log' on shell, I see 'Broken Pipe' error.

I don't see this when I do other git operations like 'git status/push/pull/commit' or anything for that matter.

I am actually surprised not to find solution to this problem on stackoverflow and having to ask it! (or I am too dumb to ask it because its something simple)

Please let me know if anyone has seen it before.

Pranav

Comment: Not sure why you would be seeing this, but the underlying cause is most likely benign. Git automatically pipes its output through a pager like `less` when appropriate, and the pipe error is usually the result of the Git command trying to write to the pager after you have quit it prematurely. One possibility is that Git is trying to use a pager that doesn't exist on your machine, so that the pager "exits" immediately.

Comment: @chepner : thank you so much for the hint! The problem was `less` command was not in the `PATH` and hence the error. Once it was sourced, the problem went away!